# Error: Unknown constructor 'DuplicateQARelController.DuplicateQARelController()

Tags: controller

Can anyone please help me figure out why I'm getting the error mentioned in the thread title? I'm trying to build a simple VF page with a custom controller.

[image: Error]

**VF page:**

```
<apex:page controller="DuplicateQARelController">
<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock title="Duplicate QA task/(s) details">


     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! releases }" var="qa">


         <apex:column headerValue="QA Release Id">
              <a href="/{!qa.Id}">
                  <apex:outputField value="{!qa.Name}"/>
              </a>
               </apex:column>

         <apex:column value="{! qa.Owner.Name }"/> 
         <apex:column value="{! qa.Objective__c }"/> 
         <apex:column value="{! qa.Due_Date__c }"/>



    </apex:pageBlockTable>

</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

***Controller code:***

```
public with sharing class DuplicateQARelController{

//Declare the variables to be used
public List<QA_Release__c> releases {get;set;}
private Id releaseClientId;


//Put all code inside constructor since it will be initialized when page is rendered
public DuplicateQARelController() {

    //Extract the Id of the current QA Release record 
    Id qaId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

    //Extract the client Id from the above record
    QA_Release__c qaRel = [SELECT Client__c FROM QA_Release__c
                           WHERE Id= :qaId ];
    releaseClientId     = qaRel.Client__c;

    //Find all QA Release records with above Client 

    releases = [SELECT Name, Owner.Name, Objective__c, Due_Date__c 
                FROM QA_Release__c 
                WHERE (Id = :releaseClientId AND 
                (Status__c='Not Started' OR Status__c = 'In Progress' OR
                 Status__c = 'On Hold' OR Status__c ='Re-opened')) ];

}

 }
```

Comment: Can you first save controller and then create VF ?I dont see anything wrong here

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I wonder why it wasn't working earlier.

Comment: Can you mark as an answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue happens when we dont save the controller before the Visualforce Markup is saved .

Solution is to make sure Apex class is saved and then VF tags are Saved .